# php array sorting

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [MF_B302] => Array
            (
                [FAILURE_DATE] => 2010-02-01 00:00:00
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [claimnum] => 1
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [MF_B302] => Array
            (
                [FAILURE_DATE] => 2009-08-10 00:00:00
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [claimnum] => 2
            )
    )
)
```

i need to sort that according to [FAILURE_DATE], does any one have a function to do this?

thank you...

Answer (score 3):

This should help you brush up on the basics of array sorting in PHP

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/

Something like this would sort your problem however:

```
usort($array, "cmp");

function cmp($a, $b){ 
    return strcmp($b['FAILURE_DATE'], $a['FAILURE_DATE']); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function failureDateSort($a, $b)
{
    $aDate = strtotime($a['MF_B302']['FAILURE_DATE']);
    $bdate = strtotime($b['MF_B302']['FAILURE_DATE']);
    if ($aDate == $bDate) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($aDate < $bDate) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($myArray, "failureDateSort");
```