# How to sort an array by date it was created

Tags: php, sorting, asort

I have an array of articles.

```
 $allarticles = Array ([0] => Array ([id] => 24,
                                     [article_id] => 74,
                                     [created] => 2011-01-01 20:48:48 ) 
                       [1] => Array ( [id] => 39,
                                      [article_id] => 94,
                                      [created] => 2011-02-21 21:06:44 ) 
                      );
```

I would like to sort the array by the created date(DESC most recent first).

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php array sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027616/php-array-sorting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the CakePHP static Set::sort method [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1490/sort).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function csort($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($b['created'], $a['created']);
}

usort($allarticles, 'csort');
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/jQmaptNl)

Comment: strcmp will work for dates? I suppose just by order of information it will work, right?

Comment: @Brad Christie: Yes, in this case it works because of the format of the date.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
function sortbycreated($a,$b){
  return ($a['created']>$b['created']?1:($a['created']<$b['created']?-1:0));
}
usort($allarticles,'sortbycreated');
```

Still waking up, so if that sorts in the reverse order, swap the `1` and `-1`. Also, this assumes the dats are actual "time()"s. If they aren't you'll need to parse to a value you can compare before you check, but all this can be done in the new function.

**EDIT**

If they aren't already `time()`s:

```
function sortbycreated($a,$b){
  $_a = strtotime($a['created']); $_b = strtotime($b['created']);
  return ($_a > $_b ? 1 : ($_a < $_b ? -1 : 0));
}
```

Comment: You should pass `sortbycreated` as string to `usort` ;) (it will work without but you will get a notice about an undefined constant).

Comment: @FelixKling: Good call, I've been bouncing between C#, JavaScript and PHP. ;p Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

```
uasort($allarticles, function ($a, $b) {
    $diff = 
    /*
    write code here to convert the string dates to numeric equivalents and subtract them. 
    If you want to reverse the order, revers the way you subtract.
    */
    return $diff;
});
```

Comment: You should mention that this only works in PHP 5.3 and above.

Comment: Nope, it does work on even PHP 4. At least that's what the PHP manual says!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sortedArticles = array();
foreach ( $allarticles as $article ) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($article ['created']);
    $sortedArticles[$timestamp] = $article;
}
ksort($sortedArticles);

var_dump($sortedArticles);
```

Or when you fetch data from database just do `ORDER BY created`.

Answer (score 0):

```
uasort($allarticles, 'sort_by_date');
function sort_by_date($a, $b) {
    if (strtotime($a['created']) == strtotime($b['created'])) {
        return 0;
    }
    return strtotime($a['created') > strtotime($b['created']) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a `strtotime` to see if they're the same?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's better to sort this within the database instead. For me it's useless to make iterations of something which will be served from the database for free.

In case you are interested. You just have to do this:

```
$this->YourModel->find('all', array('order'=>'created'));
```

otherwise just use one of other solutions proposed in the tread.